# Force Angular function to complete

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have an Angular function contained within an Angular controller on my Login page that is supposed to set some `localStorage` values

Here is the function

```
$scope.setInfo = function () {
    getInfo.getFromServer($scope.username, $scope.password).then(function(response) {
        console.log("Got here!");

        localStorage["yat"] = response.data.access_token;
        localStorage["yrt"] = response.data.refresh_token;
    }, function() {
        console.log("Error occured");
    });
}
```

The function is executed on the `ng-click` event of the login button which is posting to a `MVC controller` that authenticate the user and redirect to a landing page. When looking at the `console.log("Got here!");` statement I can see that it is not always reached, almost like the `getInfo.getFromServer` method is never called, when however restarting my application in Visual Studio, I can see that the statement was reached.

Will the redirect of the MVC controller have any affect on the completion of the angular function, or might it be possible that the application is redirected before the angular function got a chance to execute the method?

Is there any way to make sure that the method is always executed?

Comment: seems to me that the getFromServer becomes asynchronous with two params. Can you share the getFromServer method?

Comment: I guess getFromServer forgot to reject the promise when it fails to authenticate?